# Many threads are in IN_NATIVE state

Tags: java, tomcat, ldap

We are seeing some weird issue in tomcat node. I took the thread dump to see the thread status. In tha most of the threads are in IN_NATIVE status. Can some body tell me what it is and what causing this? Here is the stack trace for the threads.

```
Thread 677: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=84, line=129 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(java.io.InputStream, byte[], int, int) @bci=21, line=293 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(java.io.InputStream, java.io.OutputStream) @bci=32, line=331 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord, boolean) @bci=44, line=789 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord) @bci=15, line=746 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=30, line=75 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=175, line=218 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(byte[], int, int) @bci=44, line=258 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=49, line=317 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run() @bci=30, line=808 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=619 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 675: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=84, line=129 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(java.io.InputStream, byte[], int, int) @bci=21, line=293 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(java.io.InputStream, java.io.OutputStream) @bci=32, line=331 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord, boolean) @bci=44, line=789 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord) @bci=15, line=746 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=30, line=75 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=175, line=218 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(byte[], int, int) @bci=44, line=258 (Compiled frame)
 - java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=49, line=317 (Compiled frame)
 - com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run() @bci=30, line=808 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=619 (Interpreted frame)
```

**Full Threaddump is @**
https://docs.google.com/document/d/16YnK85jrlxvu_PpQrTQxtIWjWmAlt8AF1ddAOzvisCM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the threads are blocked for input data, possibly awaiting data from mysql server. If no data is suppose to be awaited, you have fallen on a bug of mysql server. Check 'show processlist' to see if there are queries being executed, if not -- it's the bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24995

Comment: @bestsss Nothing to do with MySQL. See the stack trace.

Comment: Looks like mysql causing this but i am not sure, because i am seeing bunch of slow queries in the logs at the same time which are taking around 20 to 30 seconds. Still i couldn't able to find the cause. Help appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Chandu See the stack trace. How can MySQL possibly be causing this when there are no MySQL classes in the stack trace, and how can LDAP *not* be causing this when there are LDAP classes in the stack trace?

Comment: @EJP, yeah, it's LDAP, I saw `fill()` only (the format of the stacktrace made escape me the root cause)

Comment: @EJP Might be from LDAP. Looking into it. And i posted full thread dump. Can you please take a look.

Comment: What do you mean 'might be'? It is. No question about it whatsoever. So you need to look into connectivity to LDAP via SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Java is written kind of like a wrapper language to C++.  Some libraries still use c++ and utilize the java keyword native.

This basically means that they called a native method that is now executing in c/c++ code.

Comment: in this particular case the thread is blocked on socket reading, it's not executing anything

Comment: Looks like mysql causing this but i am not sure, because i am seeing bunch of slow queries in the logs at the same time which are taking around 20 to 30 seconds. Still i couldn't able to find the cause. Help appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you post the whole thread dump? It would be easier to detect what is actually going on.

Comment: Well it looks like you only posted two threads. You can get the entire thread dump by doing a jstack of the process. You can find out the process id by doing a jps.

Answer (score 1):

The threads are blocked doing a read via SSL from an LDAP server. See the stack trace.